# How to test for recent-enough version of MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

A function I want to implement needs to know whether the current version of MATLAB is at least as recent as `R2014a`.

Is there a *robust, supported* way to perform this check?

(With *"robust, supported"* I mean to say that I'm not interested in fragile hacks such as parsing the string returned by version, etc.)

---

<sub>BTW, in this case, the reason I want this check is to know that I can use the function `matlab.lang.makeUniqueStrings`.  If there were a *robust, supported* way to check for the availability of this function, I'd use it instead of testing that the current MATLAB is recent enough.  Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be such a check: `exist` returns false to every variant I can come up for the name of this function.  Again, I can think of fragile hacks to mimic a proper test (e.g. `which('matlab.lang.makeUniqueStrings')`), but they're hardly better than the version-testing hacks I alluded to above.</sub>

<sub>The best solution I have found is to run the command using `matlab.lang.makeUniqueStrings` within a `try-catch` block.  This is still a fragile hack, because `MATLAB` does not offer a robust, built-in way to catch specific exceptions!</sub>

<sub>IOW, it's all about choosing the least awful hack.  Testing that the current version is recent enough (even if this test is a fragile hack) at least has the virtue of being general enough to stick in some function, and at least contain the proliferation of fragile, hacky code.</sub>

Comment: Can you explain why you consider parsing the version string *fragile*? In your view, what would the best solution do?

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis: parsing such a string involves making assumptions about its structure, assumptions that TMW has made no commitment to support.  Code that relies on such assumptions is therefore fragile.  In contrast, a method such as `verLessThan` implies a commitment from TMW to support a particular way of testing for version numbers.  It is then TMW's responsibility to ensure that such approach continues to work, even if they decide to change the format of their version strings in the future.

Comment: ...and my second question?

Comment: You are very correct that The MathWorks is not very strong at upkeeping backwards compatibility, or even so much as document in a single place the exact changes from version to version (how do you even find in what version some function was introduced?). The most robust way in any sense is to code everything in MATLAB R2006a (or whatever the oldest version is you want to support), and just keep away from newer features/constructs. But even then, you'd have to check for this "minimum supported version", which you do by parsing the version string (how do you think `verLessThan` works?)

Comment: If you code in MATLAB, you inherently code with [vendor lock-in](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vendor_lock-in) in mind. This implies the following: the MATLAB language has no publicly available spec, and the user base only has indirect influence over it. Therefore, the language itself may be subject to change without notice. Because of this, coding for long-term support and/or widespread audiences is just not something MATLAB is the right platform for...only way out is to lower your expectations and stop thinking about MATLAB as a general purpose language -- it's a niche product.

Comment: Another option (one that I often use a lot) is *not* to do any checks, but to simply *document clearly* which version it is guaranteed to work on. Depends a bit on your intended users if this is a viable option for you.

Comment: How do you call `exist` exactly?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I would use the [`verLessThan`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/verlessthan.html) function:

```
verLessThan('matlab', '8.3')
```

This will return true (1) if the current version you are using is older than 8.3 (R2014a) and false (0) otherwise. No string parsing required.

You could then use it like so:

```
if ~verLessThan('matlab', '8.3')
  % Run code using matlab.lang.makeUniqueStrings
end
```

Comment: How do you find the version number (i.e., 8.3) for each release (i.e., R2014a)?

Answer (score 8):

If you only need to care about fairly recent versions, use the `verLessThan` command. However, `verLessThan` was introduced in about 2006a or so; if you need to support versions older than that, you will need to use the output of the `version` command.

Alternatively, you can robustly test for the existence of `matlab.lang.makeUniqueStrings`. Firstly, use `m = meta.package.fromName('matlab.lang')` to retrieve a `meta.package` object referring to the package. If `m` is empty, the package does not exist. Assuming `m` is not empty, check the `FunctionList` property of `m` to see whether `makeUniqueStrings` is present. (There's also a `ClassList` property as well).

Finally, MATLAB does offer a way to catch specific exceptions. Instead of a simple `catch`, use `catch myError`. The variable `myError` will be an object of type `MException`, available within the `catch` block. You can test the `identifier` and `message` properties of the exception, and handle different exceptions appropriately, including rethrowing unhandled ones.

Comment: +1. IMHO, parsing the version string is the most "robust and supported" way, because that works in all MATLAB versions. Also, the MATLAB version some function/class was introduced in is not going to change, as MATLAB users have no influence over it (Octave users however, might). Note that your options 2 and 3 will throw errors in older versions of MATLAB; I therefore wouldn't call it "robust". But hey, as the OP doesn't really define these terms anyway....:)

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis yes, I agree - I would usually just parse `version`, as it's barely harder than using `verLessThan`. You're also of course right - I hadn't thought of this - that older versions will error with `meta.package` (before 8a) and `catch myError` (though that syntax is pretty old).

Answer (score 3):

You may use MATLAB command [`version`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/version.html) for your test -

```
['Release R' version('-release')]
```

Sample run -

```
>> ['Release R' version('-release')]

ans =

Release R2012a
```

Check if your MATLAB version is the recent one (R2014a)  -

```
strcmp (version('-release'),'R2014a')
```

The above command would return `1` if it's a recent version, otherwise returns `0`.

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to use the [`version`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/version.html) command, and parse the string appropriately.

```
[v d] = version
```

Take a look at the output from R2014a, and set your values appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

An example of what Sam meant:

```
try
    %// call to matlab.lang.makeUniqueStrings
catch ME
    %// (use regexp here to include support for Octave) 
    if strcmpi(ME.identifier, 'MATLAB:undefinedVarOrClass')
        error('yourFcn:someID',...
            'matlab.lang.makeUniqueStrings is not supported on your version of MATLAB.');
    else
        throw(ME);
    end
end
```

Robust until The MathWorks changes the ID string.

As a final remark: checking for features is not sufficient: what if The MathWorks decides to change the function signature? Or the output argument list? Or ..?

There is no really robust method in a language that is itself not robust. Be as robust as the language allows you, but no more.

Comment: I never wrote that I wanted my code to run on every version of MATLAB.  (The motivation for my question has nothing to do with that, but rather is wanting to deal with TMW's announcement that a function that my code currently uses is deprecated and may be eliminated from future releases.)  Also, it should go without saying that terms such as "a robust solution" are not referring to some heroic Apocalypse-proof level of robustness.  Even with a programming language like MATLAB, some solutions are relatively more robust than others.  I see no reason not to try for the more ...

Comment: ...robust solution (especially when it is as simple as the one shown in the answer I already accepted), even if, being in MATLAB, it won't be as robust as its equivalent in other languages.

Comment: @kjo what should go without saying is that the term "robust" has no universally accepted definition in software engineering, thus making it subjective. I, as a space engineer, apparently mean something completely different with it than you do. Looking at all the comments here, I still don't fully understand what you want the perfect solution to do. What is "robust" in your book?

Answer (score 0):

Testing for version number is barely a good idea. You should always check for features, and never for versions, if you really want robustness (and at the same time portability).

What will happen if one of the features you need is removed from a future version of Matlab? Or the way it works changes? (this is far more common than one would expect). Or if someone wants to use your code in a Matlab compatible system that does have the features your code requires?

There are some autoconf macros related to Matlab around (although I have never used one). Or you can write your own simply checks in Matlab language.

Comment: If MATLAB had a simple (i.e. general), supported way to test for features (or at least one that is as simple and robust as `verLessThan` seems to be for testing versions), I'd use it.  IMO, it doesn't (YMMV), so the question of the superiority of "testing for features" becomes academic: possibly true "in theory", but very debatable in this particular case.

Comment: @kjo testing for features is not something that the language should provide. There are specific tools to fill that purpose such as SCons and Autoconf which I did mention on my answer. The project may be written in Matlab, but that does not make it a question about Matlab programming. It is a question on software engineering since the purpose is to make the code work on systems different from the one it was developed, and that is definitely not academic at all.

Comment: Well, you were the one who suggested testing for features; if the language doesn't support it, then I'm not interested in even trying to roll my own, inevitably fragile, feature-testing utilities.

Comment: @kjo have you ever tested for features? I never suggested to write your own feature-testing utility. As you just said, that is a "utility", a program on its own, not features of a programming language. It has nothing to do with the main language of your project. You specify the feature you need, in Matlab code, and the tool tests for that feature and returns yes or no, adjusting the code as required. You don't need to implement the "feature-testing utilities", you just need to know what the features are.

Comment: What you propose is orders of magnitude more involved, and IMO no better, than the simple solution that I already accepted.

Comment: @kjo yes, it's order of magnitude more involved, but it is also orders of magnitude more correct. 1) it has happened more than once for Matlab to remove or change a feature without warning and notice (not even in the Release Notes). Checking for minimum version will not cover that. You're the one who asked for robustness. 2) checking for version means that you're limiting to Mathwork's Matlab, your code will always fail in compatible systems just because their versions numbers are different. There goes your portability.

Comment: +1, I fully support your view (except the part about the language not having to provide a feature check utility...why shouldn't it?)

Comment: -1 because it isn't really an answer, and "testing for features" is at least as complicated as testing for version, and in many cases is a useful part of "testing for features."